# python parsing xml to fetch string greater than given value

Tags: python, xml, string, parsing

How to parse through xml file using python, where i'm trying to get get "score" greater than 50 if exits. In my xml file, it does exists, it should print out 65,93.

Test.xml

```
    <analysis xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <description/>
    <alert url="/alert/224.xml" message="Hello"/>
    <warning url="/warning/2.xml">
    <score>65</score>
    </warning>
    <warning url="/warning/23.xml">
    <score>33</score>
    </warning>
    <warning url="/warning/233.xml">
    <score>93</score>
    </warning>
    <warning url="/warning/233.xml">
    <score>93</score>
    </warning>
    </analysis>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the `xml` file. Then for each score, we can add that score to a `set` which means that there are no repeats (i.e. so we don't output `93` twice).

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('Test.xml'))
nums = set()
for score in soup.findAll('score'):
    num = int(score.text)
    if num > 50:
        nums.add(num)

print(' '.join(str(n) for n in nums))
```

which gives:

```
65 93
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joe, i think following line needs to be updated, (open('Test.xml'),"html.parser")..

Comment: @Mihir Depends on what parser you need, but yes all python installs have the standard "html.parser".

Answer (score 1):

Use BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
score_set=set()
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('Test.xml'),"html.parser")
for score in soup.findAll('score'):
    if (int(score.next_element)>50):
        score_set.add(int(score.next_element))
print(score_set) # {65, 93}
```

Comment: Thank you very much mad_ for introducing "BeautifulSoup" import.

Answer (score 1):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("Test.xml")

warnings = tree.findall("warning")

values = map(lambda x: x.getchildren()[0].text, warnings)

print ','.join(set(filter(lambda f: int(f)> 50, values)))
```

Comment: No worries, you don't need to loop through multiple times, you can do it all with just one iteration but I tried to split it out to show the stages